# Split and reverse in Ruby 2.1.1

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm working on a challenge at codeeval.com to practice Ruby (v. 2.1.1). The goal is to write a function that takes a string of words and then prints it out in reverse. Here's my function:

```
def rev(words)
  words.split(' ')
  words.reverse!.each{|word| print words}
  print '\n'
end
```

What I'm expecting is along the lines of

```
#words = ["apple bat cat"]
words.split(' ') #=> words = ["apple", "bat", "cat"]
words.reverse!.each{|word| print words} #=> words = {"cat", "bat", "apple"}
```

which should print

```
$ cat bat apple
```

Instead, I'm getting the following error:

```
word_reverse.rb:5:in `rev': undefined method `each' for "\ndlrow olleh":String (NoMethodError)
    from word_reverse.rb:12:in `block in <main>'
    from word_reverse.rb:12:in `each'
    from word_reverse.rb:12:in `<main>'
```

I can't figure out why it's not working. Thoughts?

Comment: `{"cat", "bat", "apple"}` is not a Ruby object.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced. You will not get that error message with what you have.

Comment: In your example, `#words = ["apple bat cat"]`  would not be right, as that is an array with a single string in it.   `#words = "apple bat cat"` will work with the solution below. (once the comment is removed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#split` does not change the string object into an array in-place. You need to assigned the returned value back:

```
words = words.split(' ')
```

You don't need to use `reverse!`. The code is printing all words every time. You may want to print each word.

```
words.reverse.each { |word| print word }  # not `words`, but `word`
```

You also need to care about spaces inbetween.

---

Here's more concise one:

```
puts words.split.reverse.join(' ')
```

- [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split) splits by spaces by default. You don't need to specify `' '`.
- reverse the return array.
- Using [`Array#join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join), insert space between words.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method is nondestructive.  It returns the array of words, but it doesn't touch the original string.

```
irb(main):001:0> s = 'apple bat cat' #=> "apple bat cat"
irb(main):002:0> words = s.split(' ') #=> ["apple", "bat", "cat"]
irb(main):003:0> words #=> ["apple", "bat", "cat"]
irb(main):004:0> s #=> "apple bat cat"
```

What you want to do is then join the array back together in reverse order.  Which you can do all in one three-method chain:

```
puts s.split.reverse.join ' '
```

Here I took advantage of the fact that `split` with no argument already splits on whitespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `!` on `reverse`. And `words.split(' ')` doesn't change `words` so you have to continue using `reverse` directly after it or use `!`. And `words` should be `word`.

```
def rev(words)
  words.split(' ').reverse.each{ |word| print word }
  print '\n'
end
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.